# Why video in adobe-captivate8 (which added in adboe-dreamweaver) can't play in any browser?

Tags: html, flash, dreamweaver, adobe-captivate

First, I create captivate file, insert video (.mp4) into slide and publish to swf file.

Then, I copy code of htm file (that publish from captivate) and paste to html file in dreamWeaver.

But, it can't load and play in any browser which I had tried. (IE, Chrome and  Firefox)

This is picture in Adobe Dreamweaver CS6
[image]

and html file that made from DW open in Chrome
[image]

sorry, I can't show picture here.(didn't get 10 reputation)

Comment: Don't use spaces in URL path names in HTML projects. Use **underscore** (or maybe even **dashes**)... For example use path as : `test_insert_video.swf` or try `test-insert-video.swf`

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion.